# How can I add an extra OptionMembers value to a option field in a built-in business table

Tags: dynamics-business-central

Is it not possible to add an extra OptionMembers value to a option field in a built-in business table?

Eg. The "Document Type" field in "Purch. Comment Line".

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only extend **enum**. "Document Type" is still (v15) an **Option** so it's not possible now.

I hope they will change it in future releases ^^.